# Should there be a site for game mod development?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

A while ago, I asked [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/104461/how-do-i-ensure-my-custom-tf2-model-shows-its-texture) on Game Development, asking for help with a Source Engine mod I was making.
I got this comment soon afterwards:

> Is this really the right place to ask this kind of stuff?

to which I replied:

> I would've asked it on Arqade, but their Help Center says to ask questions about mod development here.

I've had a couple of other questions about mods recently, however, I've been hesitant to ask since most of their questions seem to be about using engines such as Unity to develop games.

I would suggest a Mod Development site on Area 51, however, I'm not sure it's a good idea.
My main concern is that it would be too broad, and (as [this comment](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/104461/how-do-i-ensure-my-custom-tf2-model-shows-its-texture#comment182807_104461) says) I'm more likely to get more visibility on a game-specific forum. However, the reason that I might get more visibility on a game-specific forum might be because most of Game Dev's questions revolve around creating games, not mods.

Would this site be a good idea, or should I ask on Game Dev or game-specific forums?
(If there is already a proposal for this, let me know)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Going strictly off that comment left by a moderator:

> Mod questions are on-topic here, however you are likely to get better visibility on forums dedicated to the specific game. –  [Josh Petrie ♦](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/1430/josh-petrie) Jul 23 at 21:41

It doesn't sound like a separated site would be such a great idea. Splitting that comment into its two basic reasons:

1. The entire scope of the site is already covered by an existing Stack Exchange site.
2. Splitting it off from the existing Stack Exchange site is unlikely to draw any new eyes onto the topic, because it would still be a generalized site for all games, rather than a site for a specific game. All you'd really be doing is posting under a different name.

If you really want users who are interested in modding games to answer questions on Stack Exchange, you need to get those users to *come here* first. It's pretty hard to do for existing games, as when games get released, they almost immediately form a community on a developer's site somewhere which quickly becomes the ultimate source of information for modding that particular game (especially when the developers hang out there answering questions). Trying to rip them away from that already established and growing community can be like pulling teeth from a crocodile.

Comment: +1 for developer website forum/community competition issue.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like questions about mod development *are* [on-topic on Game Dev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/104461/how-do-i-ensure-my-custom-tf2-model-shows-its-texture#comment182807_104461):

> Mod questions are on-topic here, however you are likely to get better visibility on forums dedicated to the specific game.

I think you should go ahead ask your questions there, and there's no need for a new site.